# Getting the last document of limited Mongoid query result and .count()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid to work with MongoDB. Everything is fine, I like it very much and so on. In my blog application (posts controller, index action) I have this code:

```
@posts = Post.without(:comments)
@posts = @posts.my_search(params[:s]) if params[:s]
@posts = @posts.order_by([:created_at, :desc])
@posts = @posts.where(:pid.lt => params[:p].to_i+1) if params[:p]
@posts = @posts.limit(items_per_page+1)
```

The part with "where" is implementation of my own pagination method (allows to page results in one direction only, but without `skip()`, what I consider a plus). Now, there are few small problems that make me feel uncomfortable:

For my pagination to work I need to get the last post within that limit. But when I do `@posts.last` I'm getting last document of the whole query without limit. Ok, this is strange, but not a big problem. Other than that, query results act like almost-ordinary-array, so at this moment I'm getting the last element with `@posts.pop` (funny, but it doesn't remove any documents) or `@posts.fetch(-1)`

I have a feeling that this isn't "right way" and there mush be something more elegant. Also
`@posts.count` generates second query exactly the same as first one (without limit) but with "count" only and I don't like it.

If I make the last line look like

```
@posts = @posts.limit(items_per_page+1).to_ary
```

to convert query results into array, everything generates only one query (good), but now `@posts.count` stops reporting what I need (total amount of documents without limit applied) and behaves exactly like `@posts.size` - it returns `items_per_page+1` or less (bad).

So, here are my questions:

1. What is a "correct" way to get the last document of query results within given limit?
2. How to get total amount of documents with given conditions applied without generating additional query?
3. @posts.first generates additional query, how to prevent it and just get first document before I iterate all documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the last document:

```
Post.last
```

Getting last document with some other queries:

```
Post.order_by([:created_at, :desc]).last
```

Getting total number documents:

```
Post.order_by([:created_at, :desc]).count
```

Recommendation: Just use the built in pagination

```
@posts = Post.limit(10).paginate(:page=>pararms[:page])
```

later:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Regarding the additional queries -- mongoid lazy loads everything:

```
@posts = Post.all #no query has been run yet
@posts.first #Ok, a query has finally been run because you are accessing the objects
```

Comment: You're answering questions I didn't ask :) Add .limit(2) before .last and see what it will behave like. Also .count generates additional query and I've been asking how to avoid it. I removed will_paginate and kaminari because I don't like skip() and also because they don't allow to "jump" to specific post in index action. Also, try to iterate with @posts.each after @post.first, you'll see 2 queries.

Comment: If you want to only have one query, then you need to push everything into an array. @posts = Post.whatever.all.to_a ... then the @posts.first and @posts.last will be ruby enumerator methods and not mongoid commands.

Comment: Yes, I wrote about that in my question, but @posts.count generates additional query if I perform it before to_ary, and it returns only limited amount if I perform it after. Is there any way to perform query AND count results in it before limit()?

Comment: You will need to call to_a first. So no.